# group by + case statment

Tags: sql, group-by, case

I want to update my table with `case` plus `group by` statement.

I have players table that include `salary` column and for each row there is `group_name`.

I want to update all the players who's salary is bigger than the average group salary.

First of all I tried to list the name, player salary and team average salary. I have a problem with this and I would be happy to get help.

```
select  first_name,
        last_name,
        group_name,
        salary,
        (
          select round(avg(salary),2) as salary
          from players
          group by group_name
        )
from players
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: use inner join for this senario

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: What would you update those rows' values with?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do there? Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

I still don't know which DBMS you are using. Therefore I can only guess. Here are the update commands for
sql-server:

```
update p set salary=avgsal+100 -- enter your formula here
from players p inner join
   (  select group_name gname,round(avg(salary),2) as avgsal
      from players
      group by group_name
    ) grped on gname=group_name
where salary>avgsal;
```

and for MySql:

```
update players inner join
   (  select group_name gname,round(avg(salary),2) as avgsal
      from players
      group by group_name
    ) grped on gname=group_name
set salary=avgsal+100 -- enter your formula here!
where salary>avgsal;
```

In the above commands I replaced the current salary of the relevant players with the group's average salary +100. This is of course the place where you should enter your own formula!

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY clause in JOIN statement :

```
SELECT  first_name,last_name,group_name,salary
FROM players
JOIN 
(
  SELECT ROUND(AVG(salary),2) as salary , group_name
  FROM PLAYERS
  GROUP BY group_name
) A ON A.group_name = players.group_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This sql will find the respective player and update his salary with the avg salary for the group:-

```
MERGE INTO MyTable MyTable
USING
(
    SELECT a.player,
           a.[group],
           a.sal,
           b.sal2
    FROM MyTable a
         INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT [group],
               AVG(Sal) sal2
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY [group]
    ) b ON a.[group] = b.[group]
           AND a.sal > b.sal2
) YY
ON YY.player = MyTable.player
   AND YY.[group] = MyTable.[group]
    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET
                    MyTable.sal = yy.sal2;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this @Amit Ben Zur

```
SELECT Ord.first_name, Ord.last_name,Ord.group_name,
(SELECT round(avg(salary),2)
 FROM Players AS OrdDet
 WHERE Ord.group_name = OrdDet.group_name) AS MaxUnitPrice
FROM Players AS Ord
```